# How do I test for existence of a file(s) within a certain directory before making a Tar of that directory?

Tags: tar

How do I test for existence of a file(s) within a certain directory before making a Tar of that directory?

Would it possibly look like this:

```
if [ -f /home/backup ]; then tar cf name.tar; fi
```

Answer (score 1):

In principle, yes. But you forgot to specify the actual files or directories to add to the `tar` archive. Note also that if `/home/backup` is a directory you should use the `test` option `-d`. If OTOH you want to check whether there are files in the **directory** `/home/backup` you'd need an adjustment; to enter the files in that directory into the `tar` archive, this may be what you're looking for:

```
set /home/backup/*
if [ -f "$1" ]
then 
    tar cf name.tar "$@"
fi
```